# Visual Studio GUI is see-through?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, textbox, transparency

I'm having some trouble with Visual Studio 2008 on my Windows XP SP2 laptop.

What happens is that when I start a program with a few textboxes and stuff like that, the boxes are see-through. I can litteraly see through them and see what's on the underlaying screen. Like if I only have this Form showing and behind that my wallpaper, I can see my wallpaper through the Textbox, ComboBox, even through the small cracks between various elements.

i've searched the web but haven't encountered info on this yet. Does anybody know what might be causing this and how to solve it? I'm in the process of trying to see how the text in my TextBoxes is parsed, but I can't since I can't even enter anything. I click on the textbox and I'm focused on the desktop...

Comment: Is this a recent development with vs2008, or have you just installed it?
What graphics card do you have?
Although you have provided a very precise description, would it be possible to provide a screenshot?

Comment: Well, not anymore, since I solved the problem.
My laptop on which I am running VS2008 only has 1.60GHz(the absolute minimum for VS2008), grahpics card is ATI MOBILITY RADEON 7500.
The problem turned out to be the setting in the form. Transparency key was set to white, it was also first form-run ever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... I'm not sure about this, but check the "Transparency" property of your main form. That's all I can think that it might be as of now...

Update: I meant the "**Opacity**" property, sorry.
Update 2: No, never mind, sorry. Right-click the "**TransparencyKey**" property, and press `Reset` to set it back to default.

Answer (score 2):

Check TransparencyKey, Opacity and maybe TransparencyMask?